# Using intent.getStringExtra from within an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, getstring

I am relatively new to android. I have two applications A and B. I have an activity in A, lets name it x, that would launch the application B. Now the intent sent by x contains StringExtra that I want the Starting activity in B to use. Is there a way for the activity in B to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Intent#getExtras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) and then [Bundle#getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

In Activity B:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY");
```